# reading input from .txt file in C

Tags: c, file, substring, scanf, c-strings

`john smith 21 VETERAN 1`

I have  a .txt file writing this . I want to read this .txt file and take john smith as a variable . but I can't read with whitespaces.

edit: I want to take john smith and print it in the console with

`printf("%s",name);`
I tried code below but didnt work. only takes smith.

```
while (fscanf(file, "%s, %d %s %d", name, &age, priorityGroup, &priorityLevel) == 4)
```

edit2:

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code to comment on. It is not a free homework service

Comment: If I remember right %s scan stops on whitespaces.

Comment: I'd recommend a higher level language. Python is a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task is not easy for beginners learning C.

There can be different approaches.

I can suggest the following approach.

At first a full record is read from the file using standard C function `fgets` as for example

```
char record[100];

fgets( record, sizeof( record ), fp );
```

Now let's assume that the record is already read. Then to output the first two words in `record` you can use standard C function `sscanf` as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char record[] = "john smith 21 VETERAN 1\n";

    int n = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        const char *p = record + n;
        int m;

        sscanf( p, "%*s%n", &m );

        n += m;
    }

    printf( "\"%.*s\"\n", n, record );
}
```

The program output is

```
"john smith"
```

Or you could make a string of the two words just writing

```
record[n] = '\0';
printf( "\"%s\"\n", record );
```

Or if your compiler supports variable length arrays you could write

```
#include <string.h>

//...

char name[n + 1];

memcpy( name, record, n );
name[n] = '\0';

printf( "\"%s\"\n", name );
```

If the compiler does not support variable length arrays then you will need to allocate an array dynamically like for example

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//...

char *name = malloc( n + 1 );

memcpy( name, record, n );
name[n] = '\0';

printf( "\"%s\"\n", name );
```

In this case do not forget to free the allocated memory when it will not be required any more

```
free( name );
```

In the demonstration program the string literal used as an initializer of the array `record` is appended with the new line character `'\n'` because the function `fgets` itself can store this character in the destination array.

Comment: my first time seeing someting like this (%.*s). I dont think I understand. sorry bout that. I'm gonna look for it later but now, I have john smith so it assigned to a variable? I mean, I want to take john smith and search this name in a file with same type lines..
 
`sea ak 21 VIP 4 
ali meh 45 OD 3
john smith 21 VETERAN 2`

Answer (score 1):

You can read the text line from the file and then use **strtok** function to split the text read into tokens based on the **space** delimiter and then copy the first and second names into a string array and then concatenate the values in the first index and second index to get the name **john smith**. Check the code below on how you can achieve that in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {    
    //declare the file pointer with the string you intend to read
    FILE* file = fopen("info.txt", "r");
    //make sure the file exists and is openable
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", "Unable to open file");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    //initialize a character buffer to read the string in the file into
    char buffer[50];
    //read the line from the file
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file);
    //declare a string array to hold the first two entries of the file
    //each name is assumed to have a maximum length of 30 characters
    char values[2][30];
    //declare an integer var for traversing the array
    int index = 0;
    //split the input string based on space delimiter
    char * token = strtok(buffer, " ");
    while (token != NULL && index <2) {
        //copy the token to the array
        strcpy(values[index], token);
        //reset the token
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        //update index for continuous iterations
        index++;
    }
    //use string concat to merge the names in the string array
    
    //declare the final string variable that will hold both names
    char final[50];
    //copy the first name to this variable
    strcpy(final, values[0]);
    //append space between the two names
    strcat(final, " ");
    //append the second name
    strcat(final, values[1]);
    printf("%s", final);
    //outputs john smith
    return 0;
}
```